# PropelORM - Failed to download propel/propel from source:

Tags: orm, composer-php, propel

This is my problem:

```
root@precise32:/vagrant/app# /opt/lampstack-5.4.34-0/./use_lampstack
root@precise32:/vagrant/app#  php composer.phar install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev)

-Installing propel/propel (dev-master da32413)

    Cloning da32413a8ceb295d3bb708dc311756c724a21c7b

    Failed to download propel/propel from source: The process "git clone --no-checkout 'git://github.com/propelorm/Propel2.git' '/vagrant/app/vendor/propel/propel' && cd '/vagrant/app/vendor/propel/propel' && git remote add composer 'git://github.com/propelorm/Propel2.git' && git fetch composer" exceeded the timeout of 300 seconds.
    Now trying to download from dist

-Installing propel/propel (dev-master da32413)

RuntimeException]
Could not delete /vagrant/app/vendor/propel/propel/.git/objects/pack/tmp_pack_o5glte:    
install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-plugins] [--no-    custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose
```

I failed to figure out the problem. I was trying to install propel  in Ubuntu 12.04 vagrant box loaded with Bitnami LAMP Stack -5.4.34.

Comment: Are you able to do `git clone git://github.com/propelorm/Propel2.git`?

Comment: Yes, I am able to clone it

Comment: Perhaps there is a permissions issue in your `vendor` folder. You could try deleting it and rerunning `composer install`.

Comment: I have tried removing "vendor" and running composer again. Even after running composer as "root", the problem remains the same.

Comment: That looks like a permission issue, this is often the case when you accidentally `sudo composer` or run composer on a separate occasion as a user that is not the same user you are currently acting as. A vagrant related permission issue could be how your directory is shared, if you have an nfs share and the permissions are not properly configured you may have permission collisions between running on your machine and within the vagrant environment.